# Group by columns and show two values in one cell pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have this dataframe

```
rows = [['credit', 1, 1, 2, 3]]
columns = ['Type', 'amount', 'active', 'amount', 'active']

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
df = df.set_index('Type')


        amount  active  amount  active
Type                                   
credit       1       1       2       3
```

I need to modify it so it will group columns and show both values for index
Like this

```
        amount  active
Type                                   
credit       1       1
             2       3
```

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

For a programmatic version based on column names you can use:

```
(df
 .reset_index()
 .melt('Type')
 .assign(idx= lambda d: d.groupby('variable').cumcount())
 .pivot(index=['Type', 'idx'], columns='variable', values='value')
 .droplevel('idx')
)
```

output:

```
variable  active  amount
Type                    
credit         1       1
credit         3       2
```

Alternative with `stack`:

```
(df
 .stack().to_frame()
 .assign(idx=lambda d: d.groupby(level=1).cumcount())
 .set_index('idx', append=True)[0]
 .unstack(1)
 .droplevel(1)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there a way to group it under one index? I heard of somewhat called multiindex but dont fully understand how it works

Comment: a bit expensive I'd say (just a hunch, no tests) ... melting and pivoting

Comment: @Flakee what do you mean? Can you provide an example? Here I actually create a multiindex and drop a level to come back to a single index ;)

Comment: @sammywemmy maybe but it's programmatic, i.e. independent of the nature and order of the column names ;)

Comment: @mozway end goal is to export it to excel. So credit field in this case will be merged in one cell. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to dump it into numpy:

```py
pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.to_numpy(), (-1, 2)), 
             columns = df.columns.unique(), 
             index = df.index.repeat(2))

        amount  active
Type
credit       1       1
credit       2       3
```

Another option is with `concat` - it brings up a warning which does not make sense in this case:

```py
 pd.concat([df[name].melt(ignore_index = False, value_name = name)
                    .drop(columns='variable') 
            for name in df.columns.unique()], axis = 1)

        amount  active
Type
credit       1       1
credit       2       3
```

Comment: Thank you! But here are two indexes. I need it grouped by under one index. So you can say 1 cell will contain two numbers

Comment: from an excel point of view yes (I'm assuming you are thinking in that line), from a pandas index view, it doesn't matter, since the credit value is associated with both rows

Comment: end goal is to export it to excel so credit in this case eventually becomes one cell. Do you know how can i do that?

Comment: I doubt you can do that from within Pandas; xlsxwriter might offer a way for you to merge the cells while writing to excel

Comment: @Flakee OK I understand now what you meant, no it's not directly possible in pandas